# A way to save feeds as an entry

Tags: entry-type

Was wondering if anyone had looked a a way of saving RSS feed items as an entry into craft.
I imagine this would have to be done through a plugin and a custom field type? Or is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This would have to be a plugin to pull in an rss feed and make it an entry -butt there is also the option to use the craft.feeds tag to pull rss feeds directly into your template.

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.feeds